# How can I fix this error on fetching text from pastebin?

Tags: vb.net

I recently been trying to get a raw text by inputbox, it seems to work a bit, but the returned text is not the one from the given url, it says "Please refresh the page to continue..." on the richtextbox, how would I fix this? Im guessing Im calling it wrong but I don't know thats the problem.

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
    Dim web As New WebClient
    Dim PastebinLink As String
    Dim Newcode As String = web.DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=") + PastebinLink

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub FontToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FontToolStripMenuItem.Click
        FD.ShowDialog()
        CodeBox.Font = FD.Font
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Save.ShowDialog()
        If Save.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK _
        Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText _
            (Save.FileName, CodeBox.Text, True)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetPastebinToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetPastebinToolStripMenuItem.Click
        MsgBox("This will erase all current work! we suggest saving!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Warning")
        PastebinLink = InputBox("Enter the sublink of pastebin URL EG: aXL1i5S")
        CodeBox.Text = Newcode
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setting Newcode only once and wrong

```
Dim PastebinLink As String
Dim Newcode As String = web.DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=") + PastebinLink
```

1. PastebinLink is String.Empty or ""
2. You are trying to download a string from *http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=* and to that  downloaded string you're appending the empty string from ***PastebinLink***

In your sub *GetPastebinToolStripMenuItem_Click* you are setting ***CodeBox.Text*** to ***Newcode*** but you never update it, you will always get the same content from it.

At least in the your click handler you should download with the new link.

```
CodeBox.Text = web.DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=" & PastebinLink)
```

Comment: No problem, glad it worked. Can you please mark it as answerrd, so it get removed from the open questions.